# ¿Debo y cómo migrar de GitLab a GitHub?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Primero que nada hago esta pregunta, y no se si esta mal hacerla en esta pagina, ya que en si no es algo de programación pero veo que existe la etiqueta Git. Pero si esta mal, les pido perdón.

Suponiendo que es aceptada, paso a comentar mi situación:

Me dieron un proyecto para que lo continúe, el mismo esta situado en GitLab. Ya tengo creada mi cuenta, no tengo creado las claves SSH que pide para poder empezar. Viendo tutoriales y demas en Internet, me da a entender(sí estoy equivocado alguien que me corrija, por favor) que necesito tener Linux. Cabe aclarar que tengo Windows. Se que puedo bajar una maquina virtual y continuarlo ahi de ultima, pero realmente me parece algo un tanto molesto estar en una máquina virtual, pero de acuerdo a sus respuestas lo continuare en Ubuntu(supongo).

¿GitLab es para Linux y GitHub para windows? 
Porque he tenido mis repositorios en GitHub y todo bien, no tuve que hacer lo que estoy haciendo o intentando hacer con GitLab.
Si no es asi, alguien me podría guiar o de ultima, enviarme algun tutorial de YouTube, o manual, algo para poder solucionar mi situación, que la resumo.

> Quiero continuar el proyecto sin necesidad de usar una maquina virtual
>   de Linux o de ningún otro sistema operativo

Comment: No necesitas tener Linux para Gitlab, ambos son repositorios. Ambos pueden estar en la nube o descargarse en local. Tal vez la confusión se deba a la.compra de GitHub por parte de Microsoft el año pasado. Pero no tiene nada que ver el SO, ambos tienen sus ventajas y diferencias.

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor.. usas git.. despues si el repositorio en la nube esta basado en el motor gitlab o github, es indistinto. En tu pc instalas git, y es git hablando contra git. La unica diferencia, es como se ve el entorno, y que algunos terminologias (PR contr MR) son distintas. Pero en los dos, se trabaja exactamente igual.

Comment: descargate el git bash para windows https://git-scm.com/downloads y vas a tener una consola que acepta los comandos tipo linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto Gitlab, BitBucket, Github, GitBucket... todas estas páginas no son más que servidores online donde poder guardar una copia remota y accesible según los permisos que le des de tu repositorio git. Tú mismo podrías montar uno privado si tuvieras las ganas de hacerlo.

Eso implica que son agnósticos del sistema operativo que uses, de igual manera que google drive, microsoft onedrive, dropbox o mega son agnosticos del sistema operativo, lo único que les importa es que el archivo que subas cumpla con sus requisitos (en tu caso que sea un repositorio git válido)

Las claves ssh que piden son para conectar de manera segura al servidor sin necesidad de proveer login cada vez que quieras conectar, y pueden ser generadas en windows con el cliente de git para windows. También puedes saltarte este paso pero entonces tendrás que utilizar el protocolo https y usar tu login **cada vez que quieras conectar con el repositorio remoto**.